# Change WooCommerce email header size

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the Size of the following section(header) from the order mail, but I dont know how.

[image: Marked in blue where I want to reduce height]

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce includes a helpful template system that allows you to edit custom email templates - each order status has its own unique template, and each share a main one which includes the styles.

- Create a new **`emails`** directory inside your theme folder at: **`/wp-content/themes/theme-name/woocommerce/emails`**.
- Copy the file found at **`/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-styles.php`** and paste it into the newly created folder in your theme.

You can't make edits to this file from directly inside the plugin folder, so make sure to copy it over to your theme and you can then make all the desired changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite email template in your theme. For example `yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-header.php`. This is woocommerce template and you should see something like this:

```
<!-- Header -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="template_header">
    <tr>
        <td id="header_wrapper">
            <h1><?php echo $email_heading; ?></h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Header -->
```

Hope help you.

Comment: I have been there. but that doesnt answer how you do it, but it was into the right direction.

Comment: @ilija.trkulja You can create this template `email-header.php` in your theme and update `h1` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Change WooCommerce E-mail Styles, Please go to `plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-styles.php`

[image: email-header]

Copy the file and paste this file to your template file:

Change WooCommerce E-mail Styles and paste this file to `current_theme/woocommerce/emails/email-styles.php`

Find the right class and edit the styles

```
#header_wrapper {
    padding: 36px 48px; // Increase padding to increase height
    display: block;
}
```

I hope it will help

Comment: The path in your theme to override the template should be current_theme/woocommerce/emails/email-styles.php I think. i.e. Exclude the templates folder.